# same files from different directories

Tags: file-management

How to list and compare the similar files from different directories using single command on Linux?
Let's suppose there are three files `a`, `b` and `c` in directory `/home/test` and `a`, `d`, `c` files in another directory, `/home/test1`.

How can I list and compare similar files using a single command?

Comment: Are you interested in comparing the file contents or the file names, or some other aspect of the files?

Comment: Also, "similar" implies "_almost_ the same". Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

This command will compare the file names in each directory and also report if any of the shared file names differ:

```
$ diff -qr /home/test /home/test1
Files /home/test/a and /home/test1/a differ
Only in /home/test: b
Only in /home/test1: d
```

Answer (score 0):

`kdiff3` is a good graphical tool. It can compare files and directories.